# How to display current inserted row find by current datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, cakephp

I am trying to find the rows of the current record within a group of records for display in a view.ctp. My controller named Uploads. I have id, Up_Time and value in my database table. I decided to search by Up_Time. Up_Time is a field that will display current import time.

Currently i'm using below code find by id, it fail to display the rows of current record. Is there something that can do with Up_Time to display the current record?

```
$this->set('Uploads', $this->Upload->find('list', array ('fields' =>    
array('Upload.id'),'order' => array('Upload.id DESC');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `all` instead of `list`

like this:

```
$this->set('Uploads', $this->Upload->find('all', array ('fields' =>    
array('Upload.id'),'order' => array('Upload.id DESC')));
```

Method `find list` is used when you have to get value from database and print result inside a select option

In your query now you can print only `id` field pay attention, if you would like to print all row use this:

```
$this->set('Uploads', $this->Upload->find('all', array ('order' => array('Upload.id DESC')));
```

If you would like to take only the last try this:

```
$this->set('Uploads', $this->Upload->find('first', array ('order' => array('Upload.id DESC')));
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you would like to show last 5 records try this:

If you would like to take only the last try this using `limit` conditions:

```
$this->set('Uploads', $this->Upload->find('all', array ('order' => array('Upload.id DESC'), 'limit' => 5));
```

Comment: thanks for the precious explanation! I've try the code, it will show all the records included the old record. Is there a way to display current insert record? Thanks!

Comment: try my last query added now with 'first' @user3745274

Comment: thanks again! I've tried, it will show the last row as mentioned, what if i need to show batch current insert rows? for e.g : 1 batch=5 row, how to list all the 5 current row?

Comment: check my lusta update if I have understand well your problem @user3745274